# KEGG map01100: Is this ectomycorrhizae or arbuscular mycorrhizae

Tags: taxonomy, mycology, database, metabolomics

Just as background mycorrhizae are fungi and split into two groups ectomycorrhizae and arbuscular mycorrhizae (AM). Taxonomically these fungi groups are very distinct. Ectomycorrhizae belong to the phyla Basidiomycota and Ascomycota, whilst AM are Glomeromycota.

I am really interested in the KEGG map01100 (metabolome map) called "mycorrhizae". The question is

- What phyla is the map taken from?
- Where do I find out the information/reference about how (and where) this map was constructed from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the exact answer, and a quick click around didn't yield an obvious result for the overall pathway. The KEGG annotation process is manual and may not be easy to reconstruct overall (though is generally quite high quality).

However, if you click the "Help" it tells you that there is a reference for the [ko pathway view](https://www.genome.jp/entry/ko01100). I wasn't able to actually locate this, but I was able to follow the ko pathway view to the [gene orthology view](https://www.genome.jp/entry/K19634) for specific enzymes, which in turn tells you which organisms it's represented in, which you can [click through on](https://www.genome.jp/entry/fpoa:FPOAC1_005103) to find, in this case, an Ascomycota.

I'm sure that there is a way under the hood of the KEGG API or the KEGG database view to pull this information for everything. I imagine that you will likely find a mixture of phyla because they try very hard to generalize the broad biological categories. But that's a guess!

At worst, you might be able to scrape the website to get a reasonable guess for the various enzymes of which phylum they mostly come from.

I would guess that you could ask someone at KEGG and get a more satisfying answer! I'd be interested to see how their sausage gets made as well.

Comment: Thanks @MaximilianPress the link you highlighted is cool https://www.genome.jp/entry/K19634